# CCAvenue integration with Angular 7 + spring boot + mongo

Tags: spring-boot, angular7, payment-gateway, ccavenue

I've tried to find any sample for integration of CCAvenue payment gateway in Angular 7 and spring boot but to no avail.

Did R&D and found the integration kits available in ccavenue account. There is nodejs kit and java/jsp kit but not sure how to integrate.Can anyone help me with basic sample of integration.

Referred https://medium.com/@daveinside/integrating-ccavenue-in-node-js-angular-5-b9de44091062 but the code is not complete.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The example link I mentioned worked perfect.

Comment: link does not provide info about spring-boot

Answer (score 0):

@kutty Can you please send your sample repo?

I've tried to find any sample for the integration of CCAvenue payment gateway in Angular 7 and spring boot but to no avail.